# Create sequentially numbered folders with leading zeros and move files to them

Tags: bash

I have found [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/566523/618353) and changed it to:

```
newdir=$(printf "%04d")

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.mp3' -print0 | \
     sort -z | while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do \
     mkdir -p "$newdir" && mv "$file" "$newdir" ;
     ((newdir++));
done
```

It works, but only the first folder gets leading zeros. I want all folders to be numbered with a four-digit number.

The files should be moved to the folders in the same order as with `-ls l` or displayed here in this example:

```
001_003.mp3
001_007.mp3
001_021.mp3
001_035.mp3
002_010.mp3
002_013.mp3
002_029.mp3
```

To achieve that, I added the `-z` option to the `sort` command (like used in the original code under the link above).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `bash`

```
n=0

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.mp3' -print0 | \
     sort -z | while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do \
     printf -v newdir '%04d' $((n++));
     mkdir -p "$newdir" && mv "$file" "$newdir/" ;
done
```

If you are using a shell that doesn't support the `printf -v`, then you can use a command substitution like in your original version i.e. `newdir=$( printf '%04d' $((n++)) )`

Comment: Thank you for helping me again. I missed something. The files were messed up. So I added the `-z` option to the `sort` command and now it's perfect .

Comment: @elli oops I missed that as well - I added it now

Comment: Can we have a zsh version?